# Is it possible to test GTK3 applications with tox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, tox

I try to do the right thing and write some unittests for a GTK3 application.
My stack consists of Python2.7, tox, and pytest.

Running the following with pytest works just fine:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')  # NOQA
from gi.repository import Gtk

def test_smoke(request):
    box = Gtk.Box()
    assert box
```

Running the same command from within tox (with: `sitepackages=True`) fails with a segfault:

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.11+, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/elbenfreund/projects/hamster-gtk, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: faker-1.1.0, factoryboy-1.1.6, mock-0.11.0
collected 1 items 

tests/test_minimal.py Makefile:79: die Regel für Ziel „test2“ scheiterte
make: *** [test2] Speicherzugriffsfehler
ERROR: InvocationError: '/usr/bin/make test2'
```

dmesg shows the following:

`[ 6256.753073] py.test[14834]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f80ba7e10b9 sp 00007ffeca4edc70 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.2000.6[7f80ba512000+6d0000]`

Does this mean that this a GTK issue (seeing that the segfault happens in libgtk)? But why is it only triggered within the tox environment?

I do not intend to missuse SO as a bugtracker but rather make sure I understand the problem well enough to bother the right people (if it is not me being stupid).

Comment: For a somehow similar error (impossible to run the tests suite for a GTK app although they run perfectly well with `pytest` inside each venv), I had to add `passenv = DISPLAY XAUTHORITY` under `[testenv]` in `tox.ini`. Cannot guarantee this will also solve the problem but it may be worth trying.